# What is the lifecycle of controls in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I'm looking for a lifecycle diagram for UWP controls. And in particular, whether or not it is possible for the Loaded/Unloaded events to be fired multiple times. (For example, in WPF you can remove a control and then place it somewhere else in the page, causing it to be reloaded.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is the wrong place. [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask about architecture/design.

Comment: I'm asking for a purely objective answer.

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful at [Loaded event description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am struggling to answer this overall question myself. [The `Loaded` documentation has a lot of details about object lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded#loaded-and-object-lifetime), which may answer a lot of questions.